# How to spell a word that sounds like mewnewsha?

Tags: orthography

It would fit into this sentence: ...important for the reader to overlook the mewnewsha of details and enjoy ....

Comment: Probably _minutiae_, which is a Latin word meaning 'little things'.

Answer (score 4):

> **minutia**
>   [*mi-noo-shee-uh, -shuh, -nyoo-*]
>      *noun, plural* minutiae  [*mi-noo-shee-ee, -nyoo-*]
>
> 1. Usually, **minutiae**. precise details; small or trifling matters:
>
> --[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/minutia)

A recent usage:

> *Peter Quill*: Oh you wanna talk about senseless? How about trying to
>   save us by blowing us up.
>   *Rocket Raccoo*n: We were only gonna blow you up if
>   they didn't turn you over.
>   *Peter Quill*: And how on earth were they
>   gonna turn us over when you only gave them a count of five?
>   *Rocket
>   Raccoon*: Well we didn't have time to work out the ***minutiae*** of the
>   plan.
>
> --[Guardians of the Galaxy](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0258335/quotes)